# Can not commit WFS edit in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wfs-t

I have a WFS set up on GeoServer suppose it's

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/workspace/ows
```

one of this Point layer (epsg:4326) is named `someLayer` that is connected to a PostGIS database and I've added this in QGIS. I can edit this on PostGIS if I connect directly to PostGIS from QGIS.

However, when I try to commit and edit via WFS, it returns this error:

```
Could not commit changes to layer someLayer

Errors: ERROR: 1 feature(s) not added.
  
  Provider errors:
      WFS service exception: 
          org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.PointOutsideEnvelopeException: 106.8132165731262 outside of (-90.0,90.0)
    Parsing failed for Point: org.geoserver.wfs.WFSException: org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.PointOutsideEnvelopeException: 106.8132165731262 outside of (-90.0,90.0)
    org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.PointOutsideEnvelopeException: 106.8132165731262 outside of (-90.0,90.0)
    106.8132165731262 outside of (-90.0,90.0)
```

I have set the bound in GeoServer like the following

[image]

I don't believe it's permission error, as I input the privileged user in the PostGIS connection in the data store. I double checked this because I can edit the point data from the PostGIS connection.

I wonder why I can not edit it. How to resolve this error? I just want to add one single point.

---

edit: I reprojected the layer to epsg:32748 (UTM 48s) and now I can edit the WFS layer! Why doesn't this work in epsg:4326?

Comment: it's probably an axis order issue - see https://docs.geoserver.org/2.21.x/en/user/services/wfs/axis_order.html

Comment: use the Network tab to check out what is being sent with especial note of the SRS

Comment: Hi @IanTurton thanks for the advice, do you know howto do this in qgis? I use qgis to connect to the WFS.

Comment: There is a `QGISNetworkLogger` plugin  which will show you the requests made